# colspan issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, width, html-table

When using colspan on a cell, cell takes width of cell above instead of entire row when in Chrome. Works fine in IE. Even putting 100% width on cell doesn't change anything.

```
<table cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="shiftData">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="topRow">Employee</td>
                        <td class="topRow">Working For</td>
                        <td class="topRow">Shift</td>
                        <td class="topRow">Date</td>
                        <td class="topRow">Time</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Audrey W</td>
                        <td>Justin B</td>
                        <td>Host</td>
                        <td>6/14/12</td>
                        <td>4:00pm</td>
                   </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="5" align="right" class="buttonRow"><a class="approve" href="">Approve</a><a class="deny" href="">Deny</a></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Justing B</td>
                        <td>Leigh Anne</td>
                        <td>Dishwasher</td>
                        <td>6/16/12</td>
                        <td>11:00am</td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a float: right; on the cell div that was apparently causing the issue in Chrome.